# Chrome extension Open homepage in new tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I created a simple chrome extension. When user clicks on it, It will open a website in a new tab. My question is, I want my extension to open a  new tab with given URL every time when user opens chrome browser.

Comment: as in, set the page as the homepage? what have you tried so far? why the title says "reload"?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Have you tried just having the code which you execute in a `browserAction.onClicked` event handler outside of the event handler?

Comment: I have edited my question. Now i believe its clear. After installing every time when customer open chrome.exe i want my extension to open a webpage in new tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`browserAction.onClicked` event handler worked in background.js